# android listview A intent putExtra to another listview B

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

i have a ListView with Checkbox in activity A - i want to pass data from my checkboxes that i selected in listview A to another Activity B with listview B - how can i do that (i didnt find any record for this)
[please see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64WiP.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Comment: why -1 .? all of the answers talk about passing from listview to actitvity. NOTHING talk about LISTVIEW A to LISTVIEW B

Answer (score 0):

you pass the data to activity B, activity B creates the listview, and passes it the data through the listview constructor, or you can pass the activity B in the constrctor of the listview, and than you have access to the data.